# how to filter duplicate records in multiple columns in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

How to filter duplicate records in multiple columns.

I tried code:

```
select distinct col1,col2,col3 from collection
```

and

```
select col1,col2,col3 from collection Group By col1,col2,col3
```

I need to remove duplicate rows in col1,col2 and col3.
I tried with Group By keyword also but it displayed all duplicates also.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
               string query = "select  distinct Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from Collection";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                dropdown1.DataSource = dt;
                dropdown1.DataTextField = "Col1";
                dropdown1.DataValueField = "Col1";
                dropdown1.DataBind();
                Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
}
}
```

I need to bind  without duplicate columns of col1 to dropdown and also based on col1 bind gridview at the same time.In my grid view have all columns to display
  can anyone please tell how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates from `col1,col2,col3` then both the queries should work

Comment: Your query looks prefect..Provide us the datatype of each column

Comment: Both queries work. Please provide an *actual* example of what you tried, what you got and what you expected. Are you sure that you aren't confusing rows with white space for duplicates?

Comment: `col1 and col3` are `var char` data type and `col2 is date time` data type

Comment: please show your initial table and final output table

Comment: sample data would help us understanding your problem

Comment: i updated my code.Can  please see this

Comment: Your code looks fine,Add sample data present in table as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use only col1 to bind client dropdown then why select all col1,col2,col3...

just select col1:

```
string query = "select  distinct Col1 from Collection";
```

Try below code to bind dropdown:

```
DataTable dtDropdown=new DataTable();
DataColumn dc=new DataColumn("col1");
dtDropdown.merge(dt)//dt means your output table with all column
```

Now assign as below:

```
dropdown1.DataSource = dtDropdown;
dropdown1.DataTextField = "Col1";
```

Comment: If select only required column it always distinct in dataset also

Comment: I tried this query also and i need to bind gridview also in gridview i take all the columns of table.I tried that query at same time i tried to bind gridview some field or property missing it raises that error

Comment: You have to write two separate call Or you have to filter only one col1 column for dropdown bind

Comment: I have update answer to use same table for dropdown bind check it, i haven't run just write code so may be 90% work